# White space on the left and down of wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, padding

I’m having a problem with the theme,
where a large empty space appears on the left And down on all pages
When I browse it on the phone, it only appears with the Chrome browser.
I think the problem has something to do with css, but I tried many attempts and they did not work.

This css code is added by default with the theme:

```css
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .demo-marketplace .style-marketplace.filter-course .lp-form-course-filter .course-filter-submit {
        margin: 0;
    }
}
.thim-header-info > li svg {
    width: max-content;
}
```

[website link](https://korsatacademy.com/)

I tried modifying the css but it didn't work

Comment: This code solved the problem

html,body { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; overflow-x: hidden

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the width of SVG elements in thim-header-info
Remove margin from the .style-marketplace.filter-course .lp-form-course-filter .course-filter-submit element

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).